# Using FireGiant Appx Extension with cmake

Tags: cmake, wix, appx

I have a Windows application which is built using MSVC and packaged as an `.MSI` file using WiX. The whole build is managed by `cmake` and WiX is invoked using the `CPackWIX` module.

I am now trying to extend the build environment to also build an `.APPX` package. I am following the [official documentation](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/appx/) by FireGiant.

After installing the `WiX Expansion Pack`, I have added the extension `FgAppxExtension.wixext` by appending it to the variable `CPACK_WIX_EXTENSIONS` like so:

```
SET(CPACK_WIX_EXTENSIONS WixUtilExtension FgAppxExtension.wixext)
```

I have then edited the `.wxs` source code as indicated [here](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/appx/integrating-the-firegiant-appx-extension/).

The build runs without any errors but creates no `.APPX` package. It only creates the usual `.MSI` package. In the `wix.log` file I see the line:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/WiX Toolset v3.11/bin/light.exe" -nologo -out "F:/dev/MyApp-build/_CPack_Packages/win32/WIX/MyApp-1.15.0+115-default-eb4abec2e9d2+.msi" -ext "FgAppxExtension.wixext" -ext "WixUIExtension" -ext "WixUtilExtension" -cultures:de-DE;en-US "-loc" "C:/dev/MyApp/resources/packaging/win/WIX.Texts.de-DE.wxl" "-loc" "C:/dev/MyApp/resources/packaging/win/WIX.Texts.en-US.wxl"  "F:/dev/MyApp-build/_CPack_Packages/win32/WIX/directories.wixobj" "F:/dev/MyApp-build/_CPack_Packages/win32/WIX/files.wixobj" "F:/dev/AusweisApp2-build/_CPack_Packages/win32/WIX/features.wixobj" "F:/dev/MyApp-build/_CPack_Packages/win32/WIX/main.wixobj"
```

for the `.MSI` file, but no line for the `.APPX` package.

The documentation says that after adding a reference to `FgAppxExtension.wixext`

> ... the build process will attempt to create AppX packages.

but this does not happen.

Note that adding a wrong extension in the `cmake` file will result in a build error.

Changing the `.wxs` source code without adding the extension will also result in an error:

```
The Product element contains an unhandled extension element 'fga:Appx'.
```

So I think the `FgAppxExtension.wixext` extension is loaded correctly, yet no `.APPX` package is built.

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Loading the FgAppxExtension.wixext extension isn't enough to build the .appx package while building the .msi package. FgAppxExtension does that using MSBuild, which isn't in play when using CMake.

When you're not using MSBuild, you can invoke the `FireGiant.Appx.exe` tool after `Light.exe` has produced the .msi and .wixpdb files.